# Accessing a Restful API with AngularJS and ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm making my first steps trying to get data from a 3rd party API using AngularJS and Angular-resource. So far I've been able to get some data, but somehow when I try to use it in an ng-repeat, it doesn't work.

Here's my js and html:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
function Hello($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/3823').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    });
$http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/3823/releases').
    success(function(data2) {
        $scope.releases = data2;
    });
};
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
<div class="row" ng-controller="Hello">

  <p>Artist: {{greeting.name}}</p>
        <p>Real name: {{greeting.realname}}</p>



  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="release in releases"> {{release.title}}</li>
  </ul>


   </div>  
</div>
```

And a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/72XmEOEd93sZWUBjFnnN?p=preview). You will see that the code is taking correctly the .name and .realname, but doesn't call the releases.title for whatever reason.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: I have the feeling that I'm not reading correctly the json data that comes from the API, but I don't know where the mistake is : /

Comment: StuR, already tried (actually u're right, i'll edit and change it as it is wrong) but same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $scope.releases = data2.releases;

Check the data you got back - it's an object with two keys.

Comment: Brilliant! And taking a bit of advantage, the json response is in this format: 

3: {status:Accepted, thumb:http://api.discogs.com/image/R-150-54977-1158758835.jpeg, title:Uniform,…}
artist: "Alva Noto + Scanner"
format: "CD, MiniAlbum"
id: 54977
label: "SFMOMA"
resource_url: "http://api.discogs.com/releases/54977"
role: "Main"
status: "Accepted"
thumb: "http://api.discogs.com/image/R-150-54977-1158758835.jpeg"
title: "Uniform"
type: "release"
year: 2001

How could I filter it by role? Eg. if role="Main"?

Comment: `ng-repeat="release in releases | filter: { role: 'Main' }"` Read more about filters here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter